# How to dereference a n-levels void pointer to an int pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm trying to implement the following function:

```
int foo(const void *p, unsigned int n);
```

Where *p* is actually a *n-levels* pointer to an int value and the function must return that value. So:

- *n = 0*: `value = (int)(p);`
- *n = 1*: `value = *(int*)(p);`
- *n = 2*: p is a pointer to a pointer to an int value

And so on...

So, I think that the following implementation may be correct:

```
int foo(const void *p, unsigned int n) {

    if (!n) {

        return (int)p;
    }

    return foo((void*)*((int*)p), n - 1);
}
```

But, in this code, I assume that size of a pointer always equals a size of an int, and I know it is not true. However, since *p* is always a pointer to pointer to int (*n* times), I think that maybe I can always cast *p* to pointer to int as I do in the code.

Is my idea correct? I cannot found any problem similar to this on internet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What in the world brought you to the point where you ran into this problem?

Comment: Yes, a pointer to an ``int`` is the same size of a pointer to ``void``. This is a nice and kooky question; I hope to god it's for fun and you're not actually using this for something.

Comment: Even more interesting question would be how would you create an n-level pointer to an integer.

Comment: A single cook spoiling the soup

Comment: Don't worry, it's just for fun! Actually, I just wanted to know a way to do that.

Comment: @AmiTavory: `int *` is not guaranteed to be the same size or representation as `void *`.  `char *` *is* guaranteed to be the same size and representation as `void *`.  See 6.2.5/28 of the [online C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: @JohnBode That's very interesting. I did not know that. In practice, is there any system where that is not the case? I can't count the number of times I've seen production code that would break if it was not so in practice.

Comment: @AmiTavory: I don't know of any, personally.  All the systems I have experience with use the same size and representation for all pointer types, but I haven't worked with that many different architectures.  There are some oddball platforms out there, though, and the C standard was written to accommodate as many as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Your bottom case of the recursion is not correct, since this supposes that `void*` and `int` have the same width.

```
if (n == 1) return *(int*)p;
```

Would be better.

Comment: And I believe recursive call would be better as: `foo(*((void**)p), n - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I suspect there is a better approach.

Anyway, a pointer to something is the same size as a pointer to a pointer to something, etc.

So you can cast a (void*) to a (void**).

But casting a pointer to an int may loose information, because `sizeof(void*)` may be > `sizeof(int)`.

You should write:

```
int foo(const void *p, unsigned int n) {

    //if n is 0, then p is already an int, but has been casted to a void*
    //This should probably never happend, so you should assert that n > 0

    //if n is 1, then p is actually a pointer to an int
    if (n == 1) return *(int*)p; 

    //else dereference it (by casting it to a (void**) and *then* dereferencing it)
    return foo(*(void**)p, n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this assumes that your `int` is no bigger than a `void*`:

```
int foo(const void *p, unsigned int n) {
  if (!n) {
    return reinterpret_cast<int>(p);
  }

  return foo(*static_cast<void**>(p), n - 1);
}
```

we can avoid that assumption for everything except the `n=0` case:

```
int foo(const void *p, unsigned int n) {
  if (!n) {
    return reinterpret_cast<int>(p);
  }
  if (n==1) {
    return *static_cast<int*>(p);
  }

  return foo(*static_cast<void**>(p), n - 1);
}
```

In `C` you can replace the `static_cast<X>` and `reinterpret_cast<X>` clauses with `(X)`.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's usually better to stick with iterative solution, rather than recursive, if it's possible.

```
int foo(void *p, unsigned int n) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        p = *((void**)p);
    }
    return (int)p;
}
```

IDEONE: [demo](http://ideone.com/OH7WTX)

It lets you avoid problems with *theoretiaclly possible* stack overflow for large `n`s (I have no idea why would you need to dereference 1000+ levels deep pointer, but I have no idea why you need this function in the first place, so let's keep the function safe) and avoids unnecessary function call overhead (yes, it might get optimized by the compiler, but why not write it optimally in the first place?).